# Is order of poles of functions determined by Laurent series?

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Suppose

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{(z-2)^5z}$$ is given.

By looking function, i will tell there is a $5$th-order pole at $z=2$ which is in fact true.

But on the other hand suppose

$$f(z) = \frac{\sin z}{z^5}$$ is given.

By looking just function i will again tell there is a $5$th-order pole at $z=0$, beep wrong answer says book.

If we look into Laurent series we see that highest negative power of $z-z_0$ where $f(z)$ is not defined is $4$.

**At the end of day, what i want to ask is, while determining order of pole, do we need to look at laurent series?

When one can say intuitively order of pole just by looking to function?**

Comment: Regarding the second example recall that $\lim \limits_{z\to 0}\left(\dfrac{\sin(z)}{z}\right)$ exists, so you only need to account for $z\mapsto \dfrac 1{z^4}$. And yes, the order of a pole $z_0$ is determined by the laurent series around $z_0$.

Comment: The order of the pole of $f$ at $a$ is precisely the $n \in \mathbb N$ such that  $\lim_{z\to a} f(z)(z-a)^n$ exists and is nonzero.

Comment: Just think of the series for the sine function, and divide by $z^5$. The answer leaps out at you.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** While finding the order of a pole at *z=a* for a rational function *f(z)/g(z)* , just keep in mind that at point *z=a*, *f(z)* should be analytic and non-zero there.